# MySQL - "Visual Studio must be installed" - but it is?

Tags: mysql, installation, visual-studio

When using the MySQL installer, it says "Visual Studio version 2015, 2017 or 2019 must be installed".

I have installed Visual Studio 2019 and "MySQL for Visual Studio", but it still says, "the requirement is still failing".

I should point out that I installed the 32-bit version of MySQL for Visual Studio, because I couldn't find a 64-bit version.  Is this relevant?

What would cause this and how do I fix it?

[image: MySQL error message]

[image: Error message when you click on "check" after installing VisualStudio]

Comment: maybe it is like the python extension, mysql doesn't like that i use 64 bit, but i am only guessing i also couldn't install it

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue, and it turned out to be because I didn't have the .NET workload installed in Visual Studio. You need to either select it on installation, or re-run the installer, select 'modify', and then check it in the list of options.

I left the default set of sub-options ticked (right hand side of screenshot) - I would guess that everything but the first two are probably unnecessary but I haven't checked.

[image: modifying workloads screen]

Comment: Thanks for this info.
It's really ok with the first two .NET, size 3.91Go
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBqP3.png)

Comment: This worked for me thanks. Windows 11, MySQL 8.0.31